# Add an onClickListener on Default GroupIndicator in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm using Expandable List view. In my app both the group and child have content. So I need to start activity on groupClicked as well as on Child clicked. As the default action (given in android) when I click on a group the group expands.

I want to add a action on the group indicator button. So that, when the group is clicked the activity will start and when the group indicator button is clicked the child will be shown.

```
 > a group 
     child 1
     child 2...
```

How can I do that ?

Thank You

Comment: Just out of curiosity : what difference do you make between "showing the group's content" and "show the group's children" (based on this picture : http://www.bogotobogo.com/images/Android/Android7/SmplExpandable.png)?

Comment: I need to start activity for both group and child.
Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know, It is not possible to add any action on default button of expandable list.

Answer (score 1):

you can set groupIndicator to null and then add a button to your group layout and handle whatever you want on the button onclicklistener

this link may help you to handle multiple listeners on one list item

[CustomListView Example](http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1819)

and this one for ExpandableListView:

[ExpandableListView Example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/)

Answer (score 0):

Using "findviewbyId" call id of group and child group into activity.Generate group and child group listviews in string.xml.Using onClickListener we can show group and childgroup

Answer (score 0):

The following listener will run when a user clicks/taps on an indicator:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                // add your code here ...
                return true;
            }
        });
```